# Optimizar código JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimización

Estoy trabajando en un código jquery que da la vista preliminar a la imagen que se carga.
Estuve intentando varias formas y se que no esta optimizado porque debo repetirlo varias veces, pero la única forma que funciona es repitiendo las funciones con distinto parámetro una y otra vez..
Cambian los datos de fieldId, field y preview.

Alguna sugerencia?

Muchas gracias!

El código:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var fieldId = '2_48',
    fieldId1 = '2_98',
    fieldId2 = '2_99',
    fieldId3 = '2_102',
    ....

    $field = $('.quform-field-' + fieldId),
    $field1 = $('.quform-field-' + fieldId1),
    $field2 = $('.quform-field-' + fieldId2),
    $field3 = $('.quform-field-' + fieldId3),
    ....

    $preview = $('<img class=\"imageThumb\" />').hide().appendTo('.quform-input-'+fieldId);
    $preview1 = $('<img class=\"imageThumb\" />').hide().appendTo('.quform-input-'+fieldId1);
    $preview2 = $('<img class=\"imageThumb\" />').hide().appendTo('.quform-input-'+fieldId2);
    $preview3 = $('<img class=\"imageThumb\" />').hide().appendTo('.quform-input-'+fieldId3);
       ....

    $field.change(function () {readURL(this, $preview); });
    $field1.change(function () {readURL(this, $preview1); });
    $field2.change(function () {readURL(this, $preview2); });
    $field3.change(function () {readURL(this, $preview3); });
  ...


    $close = $field.closest('.quform-element');
    $close1 = $field1.closest('.quform-element');
    $close2 = $field2.closest('.quform-element');
    $close3 = $field3.closest('.quform-element');
      ....

    $close.on('click', function (e) {readURL($('.quform-field-' + fieldId)[0], $preview);
    });
    $close1.on('click', function (e) {readURL($('.quform-field-' + fieldId1)[0], $preview1); 
    });
    $close2.on('click', function (e) {readURL($('.quform-field-' + fieldId2)[0], $preview2); 
    });
    $close3.on('click', function (e) {readURL($('.quform-field-' + fieldId3)[0], $preview3); 
    });
    ...


function readURL(input, $preview) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $preview.attr('src', e.target.result).show();
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    } else {
        $preview.removeAttr('src').hide();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: ¿Qué diferencia hay entre `readURL` y `readURL1`? Realmente nunca usas `readURL1`.

Comment: hola @VRoxa lo que hace esa funcion es mostrar en su lugar la imagen. en el div #image-preview or #image-preview1 y tambien sera el 2,3 y 4 por eso es $preview1.el problema tambien surgio de que si solo dejo #image-preview al agregar una nueva imagen reemplaza la vista preliminar de esta a la anterior, la coloca en la misma posición.

Answer (score 0):

El problema real es el código duplicado. Y la solución sencilla es la definición y uso de funciones.
Debes entender quieres que haga una función y cuáles van a ser los parámetros de ésta de modo que se pueda reutilizar sin inducción a errores.

> **Disclaimer**
>    Voy a usar sintaxis ES6 por propia comodidad. Si no puedes aplicar esa sintaxis por algún motivo, no hay problema en traducirla a ES3.

1. Declaración de variables
   De primeras, las dos variables "*preview*" son prácticamente iguales. Sólo cambia el *id* del elemento.

```
const createPreview = id =>
  $('<img class=\"imageThumb\" />').width(125).hide().appendTo($(id));

// ...

const preview = createPreview(`#image-preview`);
const preview1 = createPreview(`#image-preview1`);
```

2. Definición innecesaria de funciones
   Como el caso de `readURL1` que es exactamente igual que `readURL` y tampoco la estás llamando nunca.
3. Añadir el *event listener* a los *field*
   Ambos *field* tienen exactamente el mismo comportamiento, sólo cambian los parámetros. Ese tipo de situaciones son las que favorecen el uso de funciones...

```
const addEventListener = (field, id, preview) => {
  const closest = field.closest(`.quform-element`);

  closest.on(`click`, e => {
    const [ input ] = $(`.quform-field-${id}`);
    readURL(input, preview);
  });
}

// ...

addEventListener($field, fieldId, $preview);
addEventListener($field1, fieldId1, $preview1);
```

Por útltimo, te dejo todo el código.

```
jQuery($ => {

  const createPreview = id =>
    $('<img class=\"imageThumb\" />').width(125).hide().appendTo($(id));

  const addEventListener = (field, id, preview) => {
    const closest = field.closest(`.quform-element`);

    closest.on(`click`, e => {
      const [ input ] = $(`.quform-field-${id}`);
      readURL(input, preview);
    });
  }

  const readURL = (input, preview) => {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = e => {
            const { result } = e.target;
            preview.attr('src', result)
                  .show();
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    } 
    else 
        preview.removeAttr('src').hide();
  }

  const fieldId = `2_48`;
  const fieldId1 = `2_83`;

  const field = $(`.quform-field-${fieldId}`);
  const field1 = $(`.quform-field-${fieldId1}`);

  const preview = createPreview(`#image-preview`);
  const preview1 = createPreview(`#image-preview1`);

  field.change(() => readURL(this, preview));
  field.change(() => readURL(this, preview1));

  addEventListener(field, fieldId, preview);
  addEventListener(field1, fieldId1, preview1);

});
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias @VRoxa entendi la explicación, pero no logro visualizar porque tu codigo no funciona en mi sitio..Seguire revisandolo